# Generate Output List from three string lists based on logic

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, list-comprehension, python-itertools

I have three conditions: a transition condition, a true condition, and a false condition.

- I want to *keep* the order of the inputs.
- One list contains the transitions for each input, another list has the true conditions for each input, and the third list has the false conditions for each input.
- I want to cycle through the items in  `t_list` and output the other inputs from the `p_list` or `n_list`, but **not** the input that is transitioning.
- If the logic is `'OR'` I want to use the `n_list`, else-if the logic is `'AND'` I want to use the `p_list`.

```py
t_list = ['Input 1 transitions to true', 'Input 2 transitions to true', 'Input 3 transitions to true']
p_list = ['Input 1 is true', 'Input 2 is true', 'Input 3 is true']
n_list = ['Input 1 is false', 'Input 2 is false', 'Input 3 is false']
```

I'm defining a method to generate a 4th list for my output conditions.

```py
num_inputs = len(t_List)
logic = 'OR' #or 'AND' based on prior input

def combination_generator (t_List, p_List, n_List, logic, num_inputs):
    count = 0
    final_array = []
    temp_array = []  
    for item in t_List:
        temp_array.append(item)
    if logic == 'OR':
        for item in n_List:
            temp_array.append(item)
    elif logic == 'AND':
        for item in p_List:
            temp_array.append(item)
```

My initial solution was using `itertools.combinations()` as follows:

```py
for x in itertools.combinations(temp_array, num_inputs):
    #file.write(f'{count} {x}\n')
    count+=1
    final_array.append(x)
```

I manually selected the output combination I wanted to append to my output array, based on the count value.

I feel as though there's a better solution out there, perhaps with list comprehensions.

```py
final_list = [item for item in n_List if logic == 'OR']
```

**Ideal output:**

```py
'AND':
output_array = [['Input 1 transitions to true', 'Input 2 is true',  'Input 3 is true'], 
                ['Input 1 is true', 'Input 2 transitions to true', 'Input 3 is true'], 
                ['Input 1 is true', 'Input 2 is true', 'Input 3 transitions to true'],]
'OR':
output_array = [['Input 1 transitions to true', 'Input 2 is false',  'Input 3 is false'], 
                ['Input 1 is false', 'Input 2 transitions to true', 'Input 3 is false'], 
                ['Input 1 is false', 'Input 2 is false', 'Input 3 transitions to true'],]
```

Comment: Why does the transition go diagonally in the output?

Comment: Because I want to keep the order of the inputs the same throughout.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should work as expected:

```
def comb_gen(t_list, p_list, n_list, logic):
    if logic == 'OR':
        return [[p if j != i else s for j, p in enumerate(p_list)] for i, s in enumerate(t_list)]
    if logic == 'AND':
        return [[p if j != i else s for j, p in enumerate(n_list)] for i, s in enumerate(t_list)]
```

**Output:**

```
>>> t_list = ['Input 1 transitions to true', 'Input 2 transitions to true', 'Input 3 transitions to true']
>>> p_list = ['Input 1 is true', 'Input 2 is true', 'Input 3 is true']
>>> n_list = ['Input 1 is false', 'Input 2 is false', 'Input 3 is false']
>>> comb_gen(t_list, p_list, n_list, 'OR')
[['Input 1 transitions to true', 'Input 2 is true', 'Input 3 is true'],
 ['Input 1 is true', 'Input 2 transitions to true', 'Input 3 is true'],
 ['Input 1 is true', 'Input 2 is true', 'Input 3 transitions to true']]
>>> comb_gen(t_list, p_list, n_list, 'AND')
[['Input 1 transitions to true', 'Input 2 is false', 'Input 3 is false'],
 ['Input 1 is false', 'Input 2 transitions to true', 'Input 3 is false'],
 ['Input 1 is false', 'Input 2 is false', 'Input 3 transitions to true']]
```

Comment: This is an awesome solution! Thank you very much!